# Rendering Suits of Cards in Ruby-Rails Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, fonts

I would like to have a web app for cribbage hands, where there's a drop-down menu for value, and a drop-down menu for suit. I would also like the suit to actually be displayed as the icon. How would I have these rendered? Unicode? Webdings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use encoded unicode characters in your HTML option tags, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/9wYyf/

Or using rails form helpers:

```
<% suits = [["&#9824;","spade"],["&#9829;","heart"],["&#9830;","diamond"],["&#9827;","club"]] %>

<%= select_tag 'suit', options_for_select(suits.map{|s|[s[0].html_safe, s[1]]}) %>
```

Good resource: [Playing Cards in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode)